# connecting hostname to server

Tags: ubuntu

I have an ubuntu server installed on my server with virtualmin webmin.

everything is good the server itself....I can connect to localhost and the virtualmin manager (http://localhost:10000).

the problem is, I can't connect to it from a client computer. For example when I enter the IP address of the server, its shows me 403 forbidden error (sometimes its shows the homepage right)...but the virtualmin manager could not open...

if my website is example.com with this ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, i can't connect to example.com:10000 or xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000

what should I do?

Edit: this is my miniserv.conf output:

```
port=10000
addtype_cgi=internal/cgi
realm=Webmin Server
logfile=/var/webmin/miniserv.log
errorlog=/var/webmin/miniserv.error
pidfile=/var/webmin/miniserv.pid
logtime=168
ppath=
ssl=1
env_WEBMIN_CONFIG=/etc/webmin
env_WEBMIN_VAR=/var/webmin
atboot=1
logout=/etc/webmin/logout-flag
listen=10000
denyfile=\.pl$
log=1
blockhost_failures=5
blockhost_time=60
syslog=1
session=1
userfile=/etc/webmin/miniserv.users
keyfile=/etc/webmin/miniserv.pem
passwd_file=/etc/shadow
passwd_uindex=0
passwd_pindex=1
passwd_cindex=2
passwd_mindex=4
passwd_mode=0
preroot=virtual-server-theme
passdelay=1
sudo=1
sessiononly=/virtual-server/remote.cgi
preload=virtual-server=virtual-server/virtual-server-lib-funcs.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-unix.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-dir.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-dns.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-mail.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-web.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-webalizer.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-ssl.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-logrotate.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-mysql.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-postgres.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-ftp.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-spam.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-virus.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-webmin.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-virt.pl virtual-server=virtual-server/feature-virt6.pl
anonymous=/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated=anonymous
ssl_cipher_list=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:!MD5:!SSLv2:+SSLv3:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!ADH:!EDH:!AESGCM
root=/usr/share/webmin
mimetypes=/usr/share/webmin/mime.types
server=MiniServ/1.600
premodules=WebminCore
logouttimes=
```

Comment: You can paste the output of miniserv.conf file. I may be able to help.

Comment: post edited. check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to use the `https` protocol to connect from outside try

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000
```

or

```
https://example.com:10000
```

Comment: still get the same result...is it possible that my ISP is blocking this port?!

Comment: That can be the case. Perhaps, try to change the port to something like 81 and try again. You can make these changes in miniserv.conf file and the restart webmin.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check what exactly is replying 403 Forbidden to your requests. One possibility is that a proxy server is filtering your requests. You could try using `curl` on your remote machine this way:

```
curl -vv http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/
```

so that you may gain more information by looking at the response headers.

Comment: the 403 error has been fixed...the virtualmin manager is the problem now...means that its ok when I connect from localhost, but no result from a client computer